# magic texture moves when shape keys play

Tags: shape-keys

When my shape key moves the mesh then the magic texture moves.
download this to see
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LD6_Xq9eLbpf13SMpGlcpbfCB2w4f2Nh/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using the *Texture Coordinate* "Object" output. With *Object* the texture will be deformed if you move the object with bones or shapekeys. Instead use the *UV* or the *Generated* output. I'm not sure why it is set this way though.